# Qmake not replacing environment variables when creating visual studio project?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, environment-variables, qmake

When using qmake to create a project on Windows 7 (using Visual Studio 2010):

```
qmake -tp vc OmniScribe.pro
```

In my .pro file I have (among many other things) under INCLUDEPATH=+

```
${OPENCV_HOME}/include/opencv \
```

But when I view Project Settings -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories, in the listing, I see that this OPENCV_HOME environment variable has not been replaced and the following is contained in the list there:

```
${OPENCV_HOME}\include\opencv
```

I definitely have an OPENCV_HOME set as part of my user environment variables as:

```
X:\users\username\Windows_Stuff\OpenCV2.4
```

Note this is a network drive on a machine I do not have administrator rights with.

How can I configure my .pro file or change my qmake command to not have this happen? The above syntax is parsed correctly when using Linux so I am unsure what I need to do to fix things or where the root problem is lying.

Answer (score 2):

To expand environment variables at the time qmake is run use: $$(OPENCV_HOME)

Comment: This is part of the solution - on Linux the ${var_name} syntax technically works because it is how Linux references environment variables, which means you can use "incorrect" syntax but get away with it. Windows does not use ${varname} and so it will not work there.